# How do I increment a variable to the next or previous letter in the alphabet?

Tags: java, string, variables, alphabet

I have a capital letter defined in a variable string, and I want to output the next and previous letters in the alphabet. For example, if the variable was equal to `'C'`, I would want to output `'B'` and `'D'`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way:

```
String value = "C";
int charValue = value.charAt(0);
String next = String.valueOf( (char) (charValue + 1));
System.out.println(next);
```

Comment: But this code includes all char. not only letters, you will get a surprise when you will reach Z. (numbers etc..)
Also, this assumes you start at a letter.

Comment: I took care of the A & Z situations with if statements so that the previous letter to A is Z and the next letter after Z is A.

Answer (score 18):

Well if you mean the 'ABC' then they split into two sequences a-z and A-Z, the simplest way I think would be to use a char variable and to increment the index by one.

```
char letter='c';
letter++;  // (letter=='d')
```

same goes for decrement:

```
char letter='c';
letter--; // (letter=='b')
```

thing is that the representation of the letters a-z are 97-122 and A-Z are 65-90, so if the case of the letter is important you need to pay attention to it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are limited to the latin alphabet, you can use the fact that the characters in the ASCII table are ordered alphabetically, so:

```
System.out.println((char) ('C' + 1));
System.out.println((char) ('C' - 1));
```

outputs `D` and `B`.

What you do is add a `char` and an `int`, thus effectively adding the `int` to the ascii code of the `char`. When you cast back to `char`, the ascii code is converted to a character.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are correct but none seem to give a full explanation so I'll try. Just like any other type, a `char` is stored as a number ([16-bit in Java](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076571/java-se/an-in-depth-look-at-java-s-character-type.html)). Unlike other non-numeric types, the mapping of the values of the stored numbers to the values of the `char`s they represent are well known. This mapping is called the [ASCII Table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/). The Java compiler treats `char`s as a 16-bit number and therefore you can do the following:

```
System.out.print((int)'A'); // prints 65
System.out.print((char)65); // prints A
```

For this reason, the `++`, `--` and other mathematical operations apply to `char`s and provide a way to increment\decrement their values.

Note that the casting is cyclic when you exceed 16-bit:

```
System.out.print((char)65601); // also prints A
System.out.print((char)-65471); // also prints A
```

**P.S.** This also applies to Kotlin:

```
println('A'.toInt()) // prints 65
println(65.toChar()) // prints A
println(65601.toChar()) // prints A
println((-65471).toChar()) // prints A
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this :

```
System.out.printf("%c\n",letter);
letter++;
```