# Caesar Cipher Project

Tags: java, encryption

I have a project due tomorrow and I still can't figure it out. After reading my online textbooks for information on caesar ciphers and encryption, I still have no idea what to do. I am new to programming so most code is out of my league atm, yet this project seems way too advanced for only three weeks into the semester.

Here is the instructions: 
You are tasked with implementing a Caesar Cipher. Your cipher must take two command line arguments, the
unencrypted message and k, the amount of the shift. Your code will convert the unencrypted message into
an encrypted one by shifting each letter, one by one. It should then print to the screen the new encrypted
message. Capital letters should remain capital during the shift and lowercase letters should remain lower
case. In addition, make sure spaces are not changed at all. If you can account for other punctuation not
being changed, that is considered "above and beyond".

How would I go about starting this project and could you explain it to someone who has 3 weeks of coding experience.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**
Create your alphabet.

```
char[] alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', ... , 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

**Step 2**

Shift your plaintext. Assume that args[0] is your original message, and args[1] is your shift, as passed in from the command line.

```
char[] plaintext = args[0].toCharArray();
int shift = args[1];

for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
        if(alphabet[j] == plaintext[i]) {
            plaintext[i] = alphabet[(j + shift) % alphabet.length];
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Put your shifted char array back into a string and output the answer.

```
String ciphertext = new String(plaintext);
System.out.println(ciphertext);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is homework, so you're probably not going to get a lot of full answers. But here's some general guidance:

1 - Spaces are mentioned. So you need to take your input as a single string and then break it down (split) into an array of words. This will be the master array you scroll through, when this loop is done, your program is done.

2 - Now you need to take the elements of you array (which are the individual words) and process them by each letter. You need to loop through the characters of each word and apply the shift (k)

3 - Once thats complete, you need to "re-assemble" your phrase but adding a space after each word in your master array. Output that to the screen as your "encrypted" message.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array that contains the characters you want to encrypt (order doesn't matter). Look up the `%` operator in java and use it compute an encrypted value for each item in the input string.

Pseudocode Example

1. find normal index in array (deal with case and special characters)
2. compute an offset index using array.length % k
3. look up a new "encrypted" value using the offset index

You may find the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at:

- Scanner class to read arguments in from the command line
- java.lang.String class to turn a String of characters into separate character array elements
- incrementing and decrementing characters to add 3 to encrypt or subtract 3 to de-crypt.

See this tutorial on incrementing characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899301/how-do-i-increment-a-variable-to-the-next-or-previous-letter-in-the-alphabet-in

This is a tough project for a beginning class.

Check out this small program I made to show how to increment a character from the lowercase letter a to the lowercase letter b.

```
 public class alphabet { 
       public static void main(String[] args) { 
            char a = 'a';
            System.out.println("a currently equals: " + a);
            System.out.println("++a now equals: " + (++a));


       }

 }
```