# Increasing a character value for encryption

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, caesar-cipher

I am making a program that encrypts a string by increasing the value for each character by 5. Ex) A=F, B=G etc. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public class CharArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        String str = "This sentence will be encrypted"; 

        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray(); 

        int pos=0; 

        while (pos<str.length())
        {
            char x = (charArray[pos]); 
            System.out.print((x+5) + " "); 
            //System.out.print(charArray[x]); This causes an exception error
            pos++;
        }


    }
}
```

But the output for this is:

```
89 109 110 120 37 120 106 115 121 106 115 104 106 37 124 110 113 113 37 103 106 37 106 115 104 119 126 117 121 106 105
```

Comment: cast to a char when you add 5 to it and no need for the `+" "` So something like this:   `(char)(x+5)`

Comment: Suggestions: for encryption use proper encryption methods, for questions on SO please provide [MCVE] (with emphasis on *minimal*) along with expected output/exact errors.

Comment: I assume this is for a class or self learning experience? You shouldn't use this "encryption" to protect any actually valuable data, it's far too weak. This algorithm is known as a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), and it's simple enough that humans can crack it in minutes, even without computer help, just by doing frequency analysis on the ciphertext.

Comment: And btw, what do you want Z to be? `_`, `E`, something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increment a variable to the next or previous letter in the alphabet in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899301/how-do-i-increment-a-variable-to-the-next-or-previous-letter-in-the-alphabet-in)

Comment: No it's just for a class, not to actually protect data. And I would z to be become E so the alphabet restarts. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not forget to cast. When doing an arithmetic operation, your char is implicitely casted into an int so you'll have to explicitely cast it back

---

### Solution

```
System.out.println((char)(x+5));
```